# Gestión correcta RAII en C++

Tags: c++

El [RAII (*resource acquisition is initialization*)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) es un *idoma* común en C++; recientemente he tenido un pequeño *inconveniente* al usarlo, que sintetizo en este código (el código **no es válido, es solo a título ilustrativo**):

```
template< typename T > class Algo {
  bool enqueue( T arg ) {
    struct raii {
      T val;
      ~raii( ) {
        // Hacemos algo con las variables ...
      }
    } RAII = { arg };

    // Cuerpo real de la función ...
  }

  // Resto de la plantilla ...
};
```

Dentro de la función `enqueue( )` creamos una estructura de control; su única misión es **garantizar que una parte de nuestro código se ejecutará, aún en presencia de excepciones**. El lenguaje C++ **garantiza que se llamará al destructor**. Es el equivalente en C++ a los bloques `finally { ... }` presentes en otros lenguajes.

El inconveniente con el que me he *tropezado* es que el compilador, en su afán de evitarnos problemas, **nos da un aviso de variable sin usar**:

> warning: unused variable RAII

En compiladores *modernos*, podemos usar las nuevas características del C++11; en concreto, los *atributos*; mas exactamente, en C++17 podemos usar

```
} RAII [[maybe_unused]] = { arg };
```

En `g++`, podemos usar `__attribute((unused))__` o `[[gnu::unused]]` (dependiendo de la versión). E incluso me suena de algún `pragma _Unused` en otros compiladores.

Otros métodos, mas *manuales*, consisten en declarar y usar un constructor; de esta forma, el compilador ve que *usamos* la instancia, y tampoco nos muestra su bienintencionado aviso.

La pregunta:

¿ C++ no proporciona un mecanismo **consensuado y estándar** para usar RAII ? Es decir, informar al compilador de que el único uso de una instancia es llamar a su destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con hacer una conversión a `void`:

```
template< typename T > class Algo {
  bool enqueue( T arg ) {
    struct raii {
      T val;
      ~raii( ) {
        // Hacemos algo con las variables ...
      }
    } RAII = { arg };
    static_cast<void>(RAII);

    // Cuerpo real de la función ...
  }

  // Resto de la plantilla ...

};
```

El efecto en el código generado es nulo, ya que el compilador ve que no capturas el resultado y no generará ni una sola instrucción adicional.

Otra posibilidad... dado que en este caso `T` tiene que ser un puntero (si no el destructor del recurso se invocaría automáticamente), es sustituir esa estructura por un `unique_ptr`:

```
template< typename T > class Algo {
  bool enqueue( T arg ) {
    std::unique_ptr<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type> raii(arg);

    // Cuerpo real de la función ...
  }

  // Resto de la plantilla ...

};
```

E incluso se puede completar un poco más el asunto si le agregamos un destructor preparado para la ocasión:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void func(T arg)
{
  using ObjectType = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type;

  auto deleter = [](T ptr){ std::cout << "operaciones de limpieza\n"; delete ptr; };

  std::unique_ptr<ObjectType,decltype(deleter)> ptr(arg, deleter);
}

struct test
{
  ~test()
  { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  test* t = new test;
  func(t);
}
```

Comment: ¿ El viejo estilo `(void)XXX` adaptado a C++ ? ¿ Se garantiza la generación del código así, o el compilador *amablemente* obviará la instanciación ?

Comment: @Trauma Puedes ver en el siguiente ejemplo (https://godbolt.org/g/cz84rt) que no se genera nada de código

Comment: Aceptada porque, en verdad, no se me había ocurrido usar punteros inteligentes.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿ C++ no proporciona un mecanismo **consensuado y estándar** para usar RAII ?

Te presento el [documento técnico p0052r6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0052r6.pdf) en estudio para su inclusión en C++20 (traducción mía).

> #### Guardas de ámbito genéricas y Envoltura *RAII* para la librería estándar
>
> Peter Sommerlad y Andrew L. Sandoval con contribuciones por Eric Niebler y Daniel Krügler
>
> 2017-11-21
>
> ---
>
> ...
>
> #### 6.1 Principios Generales
>
> Los siguientes principios generales han sido formulados para `unique_resource` y son válidos para `scope_exit`.
>
> - Transparencia: Debe ser obvio de un solo vistazo qué hace cada instancia de `unique_resource`. Enlazando el recurso a su rutina de borrado, la declaración de `unique_resource` deja clara su intencionalidad.
> - Conservación de Recursos y Administración del Ciclo de Vida: `unique_resource` posibilita "alojar y olvidarse de ello" en el sentido que la liberación siempre sucede después de que el `unique_resource` haya sido inicializado.
> - Seguridad frente Excepciones: El desenroscado de excepciones es uno de los motivos principales por los que `unique_resource` y `scope_exit`/`scope_fail` son necesarios. Así pues, la especificación requiere una estricta garantía frente a excepciones al crear o mover los tipos definidos, asegurando la llamada a la función de borrado o de salida.
> - Flexibilidad: `unique_respirce` ha sido diseñado para ser flexible, permitiendo el uso de lambdas o funciones existentes para liberar recursos.

Respecto a...

> Es decir, informar al compilador de que el único uso de una instancia es llamar a su destructor.

Ese nunca ha sido el objetivo de RAII. La alarma de no uso de variables aparece para tu objeto RAII de manera circunstancial, no por ser RAII.

Puedes evitar la aparición de esa alarma configurando el compilador para ignorar esa alarma específica, pero no lo aconsejo. Otra opción sería usar herramientas específicas de compilador o lenguaje para marcar el objeto como no usado (opción que ya conoces). Y si todo eso falla, puedes hacer la conversión `(void)` como sugiere [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/136511/2742) pero para denotar intencionalidad convendría usar una macro:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)x;
```

Yo personalmente prefiero usar una función, que tiene el mismo efecto:

```
template <typename T>
void UNUSED(T){}
```

Al ser función plantilla aceptará cualquier tipo y al ser el parámetro recibido anónimo no se quejará de falta de uso del parámetro.

Comment: De acuerdo en que el uso de la RAII no es llamar a un destructor; pero es la única forma que conozco de implementarla en C++, con garantías *anti-excepciones*.

Comment: @Trauma y la opción del `unique_ptr` no te gusta??

Comment: @eferion ummm ... supongo que si, pero me parece poco práctico cuando los recursos a controlar son mas de 1 ... ( en el caso que motivó la pregunta, son 2, de tipos distintos) ...

Comment: @Trauma si usas una plantilla para gestionar los recursos es porque las operaciones de limpieza son las mismas para todos... la solución que tienes ahora es más engorrosa

Comment: @eferion [Aquí](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue/blob/master/concurrentqueue.h); líneas 1951 y 2498.

Comment: @Trauma podrías aplicar perfectamente la opción del `unique_ptr`, pero también es cierto que hay que sentirse cómodo con el código, así que si estás más familiarizado con tu solución lo mejor es que la mantengas y apliques alguna de las opciones `void` que te hemos indicado

Comment: `... los recursos a controlar son mas de 1` No parece buena idea. No necesariamente está mal o bien, pero conviene tener en cuenta el https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle