# Qt y Linux - QGraphicsItems con rendimiento bajo

Tags: c++, qt, rendimiento

Estoy teniendo problemas de rendimiento con el pintado en Qt y los `QGraphicsItems` en Linux. Se pone muy "trabado" cuando agrego cosas al pintado (grillas y demas). Puse un `qDebug` en el paint para ver que zona esta dibujando:

```
void TrackFarmGraph::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    qpenOld = painter->pen();

    painter->setClipRect(item->exposedRect);
    painter->setClipping(true);
    qDebug() << item->exposedRect;

    for(int x = 0; x < polys.count(); x++)
    {
        PolyTrack pl = polys.at(x);
        painter->setPen(penRect);
        painter->drawPolygon(pl.p);
        painter->setPen(penLines);
        painter->drawLine(pl.l);
    }
    painter->setPen(qpenOld);
}
```

Y la salida del `qDebug` es siempre la misma, siendo que yo hago zoom y escalo la vista. Es correcto lo que estoy haciendo?. Por otro lado, definir variables en el `paint`, tambien es motivo para que el rendimiento sea malo?. En caso de ser inevitable la definición de variables en el `paint`, es conveniente que sean punteros (son mas veloces)?. Gracias por aclararme estas dudas, dado que el sistema es en tiempo real y necesito que pinte con mayor fluidez.

Answer (score 1):

Los problemas de rendimiento pueden venir por varias vías:

1. *Bounding boxes*: No has indicado cómo calculas el tamaño del `QGraphicsItem`. Si el tamaño es excesivo se lanzarán eventos de repintado más a menudo y los mismos involucrarán más pixeles... hecha cuentas. Siempre y cuando su coste no sea totalmente privativo es preferible reducir el *bounding box* al mínimo imprescindible.
2. Uso de *cliping*: Ya lo estás aplicando... así que esta parte me la ahorro. Lo único que la llamada a `setClipping` es redundante e innecesaria.
3. Antialiasing: Vale que los gráficos quedan más chulos... pero esta capa de procesamiento tiene un coste que puede resultar excesivo. Al igual que sucede con el primer punto, no indicas nada al respecto, así que ignoro si lo estás aplicando o no.
4. No preguntes por el tamaño del vector en cada iteración. Aunque los vectores pueden estar bastante optimizados... no tiene por qué ser así. Si en cada iteración tienes que preguntar por el tamaño del vector estás malgastando unos ciclos que pueden resultar preciosos:

   ```
   for( int x=0, max=polys.count(); x<max; x++ )
   ```
5. No hagas copias innecesarias. En cada iteración del bucle estás creando una copia de un objeto de tipo `PolyTrack` y esto es algo no solo innecesario sino además contraproducente. Considera usar referencias (constantes a poder ser):

   ```
   PolyTrack const& pl = polys.at(x);
   ```
6. Conjugando los dos últimos puntos, si usas C++11 o superior plantéate usar el `for` basado en rangos:

   ```
   for( PolyTrack const& pl : polys )
   ```
7. No uses `Q_UNUSED`. Esta macro está pensada, principalmente, para evitar warnings al usar [RAII](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/136504/463). Si no vas a usar un parámetro de la función es preferible comentar el propio parámetro. Con esto puedes conseguir liberar un registro del procesador y reducir la necesidad de tirar de la pila (más lenta):

   ```
   void TrackFarmGraph::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget * /*widget*/)
   ```

Dicho esto:

> Es correcto lo que estoy haciendo?

El escalado es algo que realiza el siguiente nivel. Es ajeno a `QGraphicsItem`, luego el debe dar siempre las mismas coordenadas.

> Por otro lado, definir variables en el `paint`, ¿también es motivo para que el rendimiento sea malo?

Depende... Si se acaban usando registros para gestionar esas variables y su construcción es gratuita (como sucede con los tipos nativos)... el rendimiento no se va a ver penalizado.

> En caso de ser inevitable la definición de variables en el `paint`, es conveniente que sean punteros (son mas veloces)?

Eso de que los punteros son más veloces que las variables es mentira, al menos si se toma como una respuesta canónica.

Por supuesto que es más rápido copiar un puntero que un objeto pesado:

```
struct POO
{
  int array[100];
};

POO var1, var2, *ptr1, *ptr2;
POO var2 = var1; // Se copia el array -> pesado
ptr1 = ptr2;     // Se copian direcciones de memoria -> ligero
```

Pero los tiempos son los mismos cuando se trabaja con tipos más pequeños:

```
int var1, var2;
int *ptr1, *ptr2;

// Ambas operaciones consumen los mismos ciclos de reloj
var1 = var2;
ptr1 = ptr2;
```

Y, por otro lado, los punteros añaden una indirección que debe ser resuelta cada vez que se pretenda acceder a información del objeto apuntado. Dicho de otra forma, los punteros penalizan el acceso al objeto:

```
POO objeto;
POO* ptr;

objeto.funcion(); // Llamada directa -> más rápido
ptr->funcion(); // Añade indirección -> más lento
```

Una posible excepción a este caso serían las funciones virtuales... pero no creo que sea un tema que se vaya a aplicar en tu caso.

Comment: excelente tu respuesta, muchas cosas las sabia y no las recordaba, otras no pudieron estar mejor explicadas!. Respecto al pto 1 de tus comentarios, SI muestro un area excesiva, toda la pantalla donde escalo un area de 2mil mts cuadrados, no encuentro opcion,es un banderillero satelital, donde el usuario define el campo donde va a trabajar, luego hace zoom y vé parte del grafico, se te ocurre alguna forma de mejorar eso?. Respecto al punto 3, saqué el antialising de la vista que lo usaba toda la aplicacion, solo lo aplico en aquellos QGraphicsItem que realmente lo necesitan.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres La caja de cada `QGraphicsItem` debería estar limitada al área mínima que englobe los `PolyTrack` que contiene.En este caso la caja la podrías calcular incrementalmente... Cada vez que se añada una `PolyTrack` o se añada o modifique un punto de la misma, se comprueba si esos nuevos puntos forman parte de la caja y si no es así se redimensiona... es complicado dar consejos más percisos sin conocer a fondo la aplicación

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta y comentarios. Me han ayudado mucho!

Comment: Vuelvo sobre este tema porque los problemas de rendimiento continuan. Estoy dibujando un camino, de acuerdo a los puntos gps, pero a medida que avanzo y aumenta la cantidad de puntos recibidos, el rendimiento se viene abajo. Existe alguna manera de que parte del dibujo se quede congelado y solo re-dibuja la ultima parte?. Se me ocurre que asi mejoraria el rendimiento pero realmente no sé si se pude y como se haria.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres podrías  generar el camino en un mapa de bits y volcar ese mapa dr bits en cada operación de refresco... aunque si trabajases a nivel de opengl no deberias tener problemas